# Cassandra row cache - does it always serve data from ram?

Tags: cassandra

Row cache loads whole row into ram on first access of single column. Updates and inserts of new columns update row cache - it can be seen as write through.

Assuming that I have enough ram to cache my row(s), can I be sure that read access will be always served from ram, independent of updates/inserts on cached rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: yes.  Row cache will get you down into microseconds, not ms.

Longer answer: technically only after the first read, writes will not be added to the cache unless there is an existing entry for it.  Cassandra does support periodically saving its caches so it can prewarm them on next restart.

Answer (score 0):

yes, but I also read it only improves performance by like 5% or so and that in 95% of cases you should never turn it on.

On the playOrm project, we are wondering if it would increase performance by 40% or so or even 100% as we would only cache rows from index tables which when spread across the cluster would speed up all our queries.  We are already at 60ms for a query on 1,000,000 rows in a partition using S-SQL (Scalable SQL) and it may get faster with that as well as once playOrm adds nested lookahead loop joins which may likely be faster than the old DBMS nested block loop join.